# Testing Library - behavior of passed functions

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I need to explain behavior of `react-testing-library`.
I'm trying to test my login page which works fine in browser but I am not able to pass any test.

Currently I am facing two problems:

1. `this.props.anyFunction` which is passed from test throws `not a function`
2. component is not being re-rendered on state change

*Login.test.js*:

```
let __login = render(<Login onLogin={()=>console.log('Im in!')}/>);
// fill some inputs
fireEvent.click(submit);
```

---

#### If user is logged in

I want just to console.log this situation at this moment but `Login` component throws error `this.props.onLogin is not a function` even if it is passed.

---

#### If user is NOT logged in

In this situation I render message in *Login.js*:

```
<div role="alert" className="text-danger px-2 mb-1">
   {_(`login.error.${this.state.error}`)}
</div>
```

which works fine in browser. So I've tried to catch it in *Login.test.js*:

```
const alert = await __login.findByRole('alert');
```

which throws error `Unable to find an element with the role "alert"`. In dump I see whole rendered login page but nothing has changed (component did not re-render after unsucessful try).

---

Is there anything what I didn't understand well?
Is there any way how to debug state of tested component?

---

#### Full code example

As requested I'm providing full code example. May the `router` or `socket.io` cause break?
*Login.js*

```
class Login extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {email:'', password:'', error:false}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // I know this is not best way how to handle authorization, but it's just for now
        this.props.io.on('onTokenResponse',(response)=> {
            if (response.error) {
                this.setState({error:response.error});
                return;
            }
            if (!response.token) {
                this.setState({error:'unknown error'});
                return;
            }
            sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response));
            this.props.onLogin();
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
    }

    handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.io.emit('onTokenRequest',{email:this.state.email, password:this.state.password});
    };

    handleChange=(e)=>
        this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});

    Message=()=>
        this.state.error && <div role="alert" className="text-danger px-2 mb-1">{_(`login.error.${this.state.error}`)}</div>;

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="login-box mt-5">
                {this.Message()}
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    {['email','password'].map((e)=>
                        <input key={e} name={e} type={e} placeholder={e} required="required"
                               className="form-control mb-2"
                               value={this.state[e]}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    )}
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary text-capitalize w-100">
                        {_('login.submit')}
                    </button>
                </form>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

*Login.test.js*

```
test('renders without crashing', async () =>
{
    const ioClient = io.connect(config.webSocketServer);
    const onLogin = jest.fn();

    let __login = render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Login io={ioClient} onLogin={onLogin}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );

    fillAndCheckInput('email','jaxpcze@gmail.com');
    fillAndCheckInput('password','wrong');
    let submit = __login.getByText('přihlásit');
    fireEvent.click(submit);
    const alert = await __login.findByRole('alert');

    fillAndCheckInput('password','right');
    fireEvent.click(submit);
    await expect(onLogin).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    function fillAndCheckInput(placeholder,value) {
        let __input = __login.getByPlaceholderText(placeholder);
        fireEvent.change(__input,{target:{value:value}});
        expect(__input.value).toBe(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share your login form code and the test code?

Comment: @JonathanIrwin I've added full example